# Android Studio Device Monitor Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin, android-device-monitor

I have Java 9 installed on Mac OS. Android Studio is running well but I cannot open the Device Monitor.

I get following error:

```
/Users/tobias/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/monitor ; exit;
Tobiass-MBP:~ tobias$ /Users/tobias/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/monitor ; exit;
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage (file:/Users/tobias/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

and in the log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-17 02:05:03.013
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```